# How to Remove extra spaces from Top and Bottom of Image

Tags: android

How to remove extra spaces from top and bottom of image, see below screen shot:

[image]

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/About"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />
```

Comment: try this android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: Also set this property android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: @ArvindKanjariya also thanks to you +1 for easy solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you need to use this android:adjustViewBounds="true".Try this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/About"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: nice +1 for easy solution, will tick on accept after 5mins, already ticked on useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as image view.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/About"
    android:src="@drawable/menu"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbtn_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/menu" />
```